# Login onto website using python

Tags: python, authentication

I would like to login to https://pyckio.com/signin and have tried the following:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("https://pyckio.com/signin/")

for f in br.forms():
    print f

br.select_form(nr = 0)
br.form['email'] = 'myemail'
br.form['password'] = 'mypassword'
br.submit()

print br.response().read()
```

It seems this doesn't work :-(

I'd need to login to be able and scrape password protected content from this site, not necessarily need to use the mechanize module, though.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might need to give a bit more detail than just "doesn't work".